# QGIS Copy Attribute Table To Excel - where does the new lines come from?

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, export, excel, well-known-text

I have an attribute table with 3100 lines.

I selected the whole table and pressed the button 'copy selected rows to clipboard', afterwards I pasted them into an excel-table.

Now I have 27 lines more. There are no attributes in these lines, only information in the wkt_geom row. In some lines are only numbers not even starting with PolygonZ. Where does these lines come from?